# trying to create a local notification but getting error " cannot call value of non function type uilocalnotification " in swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, uilocalnotification

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComp.year = 2015;
        dateComp.month = 11;
        dateComp.day = 20;
        dateComp.hour = 0;
        dateComp.minute = 10;
        dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

        var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
        var date:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!
        //var date:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)

        var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
        notification.alertBody = "HI, noti "
        notification.fireDate  = date

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications(notification)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
//trying to create a local notification but getting error " cannot call value of non function type uilocalnotification " in swift 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `scheduleLocalNotification`, not `scheduledLocalNotifications` (note schedule not schedule**d**):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: just now tried that but still getting an error "value of type 'uiapllication' has no member 'scheduledlocalnotification'"

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `scheduleLocalNotification` on `UIApplication.sharedApplication()`?  I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: yes but its  still showing error :(

Comment: Are you sure you typed my answer in exactly?  What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Copy and paste to be sure

Comment: its 7.2 beta version

Comment: hey JAL Sorry ;D my fault ! i did copy and paste now working ! a big thanks to you