# local notification ios in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, notifications

The line `UiApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotifications(notification)` gives me the following error `value of type 'uiapplication' has no member ' schedulelocalnotification'`

How can I solve this?

```
import UIKit
```

class SchermataIniziale: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  let notification = UILocalNotification()

    if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
        notification.alertTitle = "Mille Favole"
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    notification.alertBody = "Ricordati di leggere la favola questa sera"

    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)

    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1

    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotifications(notification)

    //showinitial = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

Comment: Do not use prints to show your code, insert the text instead.

Comment: Please share the complete declaration of the `localNotification` variable

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `scheduleLocalNotification` instead of `scheduledLocalNotification`

Example:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

See here: [trying to create a local notification but getting error " cannot call value of non function type uilocalnotification " in swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812208/trying-to-create-a-local-notification-but-getting-error-cannot-call-value-of-n)

Comment: I corrected following the link of an earlier application to the same problem but I have not solved . Now , on this line UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotifications(notification)   comes out this error "value of type 'uiapplication' has no member 'schedulelocalnotification'

Comment: I write the correct code in the application with the error

Comment: you need to use **scheduleLocalNotification** NOT **scheduleLocalNotifications**

Comment: I know I have not noticed too late. too many hours in front of the mac that's what lead. sorry